# So I have two dates column in pandas, I need to find which all orders where completed in less than a month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

The two columns are close_date  and created_on. I have done

```
products_pipeline_and_teams['Days_Taken_to_close']=products_pipeline_and_teams.close_date - products_pipeline_and_teams.created_on
```

and got the results like this

```
0    12 days
1    36 days
2        NaT
3    77 days
4    68 days
5        NaT
6   113 days
7     9 days
8    14 days
9        NaT
Name: Days_Taken_to_close, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

how do I find result where number of days is more than > 30?

I have tried this

```
products_pipeline_and_teams['Days_Taken_to_close'] < 30
```

Its giving error like this
Invalid comparison between dtype=timedelta64[ns] and int

Comment: `products_pipeline_and_teams['Days_Taken_to_close'].dt.days < 30` should also work with out an additional import.

Answer (score 1):

try `< timedelta(days = 30)`

You have to import timedelta like `from datetime import timedelta`.